# History of Turbulence suggestions

Tags: fluid-dynamics, resource-recommendations, history, turbulence

I am looking for extensive historical accounts of turbulence that ideally is strong in math and physics (at least giving references).

Any suggestions?

The only book I found is "A Voyage Through Turbulence "

Comment: This is a much better fit for history of science than for physics.

Comment: I am not looking for just qualitative descriptions or biographical stories. I mostly want  the main history of the ideas filled with technical lemmas and theorems.

Answer (score 2):

I like the Darigol [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199559112) that you mention. There is also Uriel Frisch, on [Turbulence: The Legacy of Kolomogorov](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521457130).